# JSqlParser for Data Lineage?

Tags: jsqlparser

We are a data warehouse development team and most of our ETL logic can be expressed as a series of SQL select statements.  I am looking for a tool to extract data lineage in a structured manner by parsing the queries.

The query and the simplified lineage output would look like this:

Query:

```
SELECT A AS COLUMN_1, B AS COLUMN_2, A+B AS COLUMN_SUM FROM MYTABLE;
```

Output

```
COLUMN_1: MYTABLE.A
COLUMN_2: MYTABLE.B
COLUMN_3: MYTABLE.A
COLUMN_3: MYTABLE.B
```

Is JSQLParser a good tool for this purpose?  Any pointers or experiences on how to use the tool would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

**JSqlParser** does the parsing and gives you a structured way to look at your SQL. By the way **JSqlParser** is pretty good at this.

But it has no knowledge about your database schema, therefore it cannot know if column_1 A is from table MYTABLE. A more obvious example would be

```
select a, b from table1, table2
```

This knowledge must somehow injected by you :).

To make a simple parse do something like

```
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
```

To extract used columns you could use the TablesNamesFinder utility, provided by JSqlParser like

```
Select selectStatement = (Select) statement;
TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder() {
      @Override
      public void visit(Column tableColumn) {
           System.out.println(tableColumn);
      }
};
System.out.println(" and tables=" + tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(selectStatement));
```

As you see one way to surf your data is some kind of visitor pattern.

If you have more questions feel free to use JSqlParsers gitter room or file an issue at github.